# Tastypie foreign Key relationship 'dict' object has no attribute 'obj'

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm having a problem with tastypie and I just can't find what caused it. Similar question without answers: [Tastypie foreign key relationship throwing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050847/tastypie-foreign-key-relationship-throwing-error)

Resource:

```
class VoteResource(ModelResource):
    choice = fields.ToOneField(ChoiceResource, 'choice', full=True)
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Vote.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'vote'
        '''...'''
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
            'id': ALL,
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
            'choice': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
        }

    def hydrate(self, bundle):    
        bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
        return bundle
```

Request payload for creating the object:

```
{
  "choice": "/api/v1/choice/210/"
}
```

(user is getting added automatically through hydrate). The exception is thrown in ressources.py inside `full_hydrate`. According to django console my object is getting loaded correctly.

The line inside tastypie causing this is

```
setattr(bundle.obj, field_object.attribute, value.obj) # value obj is the evil one
```

[Tastypie sourcecode here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L893)

What's killing me is, that it worked like 2 days ago. I added 1 other resource without touching choice, user or any other connected with the model. I checked the recent commit history and the resource is untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugged my way through the tastypie source and solved my problem.

Looks like tastypie is calling dehydrate on related objects first. Because of a misunderstanding, I returned the bundle's data in `choice`'s dehydrate instead of the actual bundle itself.

When tastypie dehydrates `choice`, it obviously does not get a bundle object and therefore does not have `obj`.